# Apex CPU limit exceeded on Batch start method

Tags: batch, schedulebatch, cpulimit

I have an scheduled batch that processes records but I'm hitting CPU limit exceeded error on `start` method.

This is my code (SortLogicBatchQuery retrieves ~500000 records):

```
public BatchSortProjects(){
    this.query = System.Label.SortLogicBatchQuery;
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<WS2_Project__c> scope){
    this.groupProjects(scope);
    if(this.projectsByCriteria.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }
    this.manageProjectsOrder();
    Database.update(this.projectById.values());
}

@SuppressWarnings('PMD.EmptyStatementBlock')
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){}

public void execute(SchedulableContext scon){
    Database.executeBatch(new BatchSortProjects(), 2000);
}
```

But when debugging the error is being triggered on start method.

Is this something I need to fix? Or is this the proper behaviour of the batch?

Regards,

Comment: What does the query look like (please [edit] to add it)? NB: using a label as a configuration value is an anti-pattern. You should be using custom metadata or custom settings. You would have difficulty getting this sort of structure through security review since you open the code up to arbitrary SOQL injection by anyone who can access where you set the query configuration.

Comment: Hi @PhilW I got the solution. This was because of a subquery running inside the query. Now it's working fine! Thanks for your help!